# Better way to work with a slice in go

Tags: go, slice

I have a conceptual question while working with `slice` in Go.

Suppose, we want to write a function to perform an operation on a slice of strings and return the new slice.
The parameters for the above-said function are the original slice of strings and the operation to be performed on the items.

Method-01: Declaring an empty slice and appending new values to it

```
func Operation1(original []string, converter func(string) string) []string { 
    var converted []string
    for _, item := range original {
        converted = append(converted, converter(item))
    }
    return converted
}
```

Method-02: Allocating a definite-sized slice and indexing the values.

```
func Operation2(original []string, converter func(string) string) []string {
     // since the operation on each item cannot lead to its deletion from the slice
    converted := make([]string, len(original))

    for index, item := range original {
        converted[index] = converter(item)
    }
    return converted
}
```

Q1. I would like to know which of the above functions/techniques for declaring and accessing elements of a slice is idiomatic in Go code.

Q2. I tried both the functions on a bunch of tests and found that `Operation1` function performs slightly faster than `Operation2`. Any reasons behind this observation are welcomed.

P.S: I am 3 days into learning Go and come from a Python background. I know it's off-topic, yet suggestions for helpful resources will be a plus.

Comment: operation2 would not compile since `index` is not declared. I assume you mean `for index, item := range original {`

Comment: operation2 should is idiomatic, and should be the fasted. How many items does your `original` contain?

Comment: this is also a good read: https://blog.golang.org/slices

Comment: The first may even be more efficient at times because it's always allocating powers of two. In practice append amortizes so well it rarely matters, and I usually start from the first form since it doesn't allocate anything on a `nil` input and will return a `nil` slice.

Comment: you can reserve capacity in the first example by using `make([]string, 0, len(original))` and then use append. there really isn't much difference between the two. Both are perfectly fine.

Comment: @RickyA Yes, you are correct. Thanks for pointing out the typo. I have updated the question.

Comment: @RickyA I have made the comparison for sizes ranging from 2 to 10.

Comment: That is not enough to see a difference. If you keep in that range both methods are perfectly fine. The second one only gets faster with large slice sizes.

Comment: Not 100% related, but take a look at this article as well, it came in handy for me when I moved away from python. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks

Comment: A minor note: accessing a slice using indexing performs bounds checks at least for some accesses (that is, unless the compiler can prove otherwise) while accessing via `range` does not. Still, it's all micro optimizations. Don't think of them until required, then measure on realistic data.